# What is the meaning of "Hip" in the given context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm having difficulty interpreting the meaning of "Hip" even after consulting the dictionary.

Let me give the meanings given by the [online Oxford dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hip--3):

> **hip 1 |hip|**
>   *noun*
>   1. a projection of the pelvis and upper thigh bone on each side of the body in human beings and quadrupeds.
>     • ( hips) the circumference of the body at the buttocks : *a sweater tied around the hips*.
>      • a person's hip joint : *she ran into a fence and dislocated her hip*.
>   2. the sharp edge of a roof from the ridge to the eaves where two sides meet.
>
> *PHRASES*
>   **on the hip** *archaic*: at a disadvantage.
>
> *ORIGIN*
>    Old English hype, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch heup and German Hüfte.
>
> **hip 2 |hɪp| |hɪp| (also rose hip)**
>   *noun*
>   the fruit of a rose, esp. a wild kind.
>
> *ORIGIN*
>    Old English hēope, hīope; related to Dutch joop and German Hiefe.
>
> **hip 3 |hɪp| |hɪp|**
>   *adjective* ( hipper |ˈhɪpər|, hippest |hɪp1st|) informal
>   following the latest fashion, esp. in popular music and clothes : *it's becoming hip to be environmentally conscious*.
>   • understanding; aware : *he's trying to show how hip he is to Americana*.
>
> *DERIVATIVES*
>   *hiply adverb*
>   *hipness |ˈhɪpn1s| noun*
>   *ORIGIN*
>   early 20th cent.: of unknown origin.
>
> **hip 4 |hɪp| |hɪp|**
>   *exclamation*
>   introducing a communal cheer : hip, hip, hooray!
>
> *ORIGIN* mid 18th cent.: of unknown origin.

Now please consider the following sentence:

> Ramu wore a T-shirt with a logo of his news paper and old pair of jeans. He looked unusually **hip** for someone in a crisis.

what does the **hip** imply here?

Comment: Why the down votes? Think this is GR?

Comment: @kris it could be because, of all the options for part of speech, only an adjective would fit the pattern so it doesn't display so much prior research or thought into the issue.

Comment: @simchona Easy to say for us who know the contextual implication of the word. When you do not know what the word means, where do you look? And from what perspective will you do prior research? Where do you *begin*? I've been there myself.

Comment: @kris even without the actual word, the pattern is "he looked _____". Noun won't fit. Verb won't either. This isn't dependent on knowing how "hip" might be used.

Comment: Try each of the 4 defintions. See which one fits the context. Spoiler alert: it's #3.

Answer (score 6):

This *hip* means cool or trendy.

> Ramu wore a T-shirt with a logo of his newspaper and old pair of jeans. He looked unusually *cool* for someone in a crisis.

The preceding sentence describes Ramu's clothes. That would rule out hip<sup>1</sup> and hip<sup>2</sup>, since we're talking about neither a pelvic bone nor part of a rose; however hip<sup>3</sup> is related to fashion, "**especially clothes**". So, that old pair of jeans and T-shirt must have been especially [*fashionable* or *trendy*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/fashionable?s=t).

Ergo: it's the third meaning in the definition you included:

> *adjective (**hipper, hippest**)*
>   *informal*
>   following the latest fashion, especially in popular music and clothes:
>   *it’s becoming hip to be environmentally conscious*